# Rails, error in rack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rack

I am assuming I have a rack issue but not sure where? I keep getting this when I launch my server:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:133:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
    from /var/www/gmd-chain-splash/config.ru:2:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Show us your `config.ru`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'` in your Gemfile file and run bundle update